# Newbie question f2c compilation problem: cc1plus error: /include: not a directory What does this mean?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am having problems with compiling code on my Mac (OS X, 10.6.5).

The code uses f2c.

I don't understand the error, and would really appreciate any help.  I wondered if it might be a problem with my compiler, and just in case I reinstalled Xcode, which installs a new g++ compiler.  But I still get the same error.

Here's the error:

```
cc1plus: error: /include: not a directory
cc1plus: error: /lib: not a directory
make: *** [Task1.o] Error 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an error in the installation of your gcc compiler. It seems it may be looking for includes in `/usr/include`, but it is missing the first part of the directory. Try executing:

```
$ gcc -v
```

to see what directories the gcc you're using has by default. In my case, I see

```
--prefix=/usr
```

as one of the options.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Diego.  Here's what I get:                 Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5659~1/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)

Comment: What I don't understand is that the compiler was working just fine yesterday.  Also, I have reinstalled it by reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: You can see the problem there: you've got the `--with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1` that should read  `--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` (note the `/usr`). So the problem is the g++ installation on your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot Diego...  So do you know how I can fix this?  I already reinstalled Xcode twice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any Mac around :( I just happen to know how the gcc should be configured, but not how to install it in Mac... Sorry.