# Installing f2c on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, compiler-construction, fortran

I used f2c builds from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/buildf2c and http://hamishrickerby.com/2009/02/20/installing-f2c-on-a-mac/#disqus_thread, but none of them worked.

I followed the installation instructions. All goes well until step 4:

---

### 4. Creating and installing f2c header file f2c.h ...

```
make: `f2c.h' is up to date.
mkdir: /usr/local/include: File exists
cp: /usr/local/include is not a directory
```

### ... done.

### 5. Creating and installing f2c library libf2c.a ...

```
cp signal1.h0 signal1.h
cp sysdep1.h0 sysdep1.h
/usr/bin/cc -c f77vers.c
cc1: error: /usr/local/include: not a directory
make: *** [f77vers.o] Error 1
cp: libf2c.a: No such file or directory
ranlib: can't open file: /usr/local/lib/libf2c.a (Permission denied)
```

### ... done.

### 6. Creating and installing f2c translator ...

```
/usr/bin/cc -O -o xsum xsum.c
cc1: error: /usr/local/include: not a directory
make: *** [xsum] Error 1
cp: f2c: No such file or directory
ln: /bin/f2c: Permission denied
```

### ... done.

### 7. Installing fc script ...

```
cp: /usr/local/bin/fc: Permission denied
ln: /bin/fc: Permission denied
ln: /bin/f77: Permission denied
```

### ... done.

### 8. Installing man pages ...

```
cp: /usr/share/man/man1/f2c.1: Permission denied
```

### ... done.

### 9. Cleaning up ...

```
rm -f *.o f2c sysdep.hd tokdefs.h f2c.t
rm -f libf2c.a *.o arith.h signal1.h sysdep1.h
```

... All done!

The results is of course:
    -bash: f2c: command not found

I repaired disk permissions before trying another time, but this had no effect. I don't understand what went wrong. I previously installed Xcode 4 and Intel fortran. The latter works well.

My problem seems similar to one that was described in another thread
[Newbie question f2c compilation problem: cc1plus error: /include: not a directory What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323471/newbie-question-f2c-compilation-problem-cc1plus-error-include-not-a-director)
As in the mentioned thread, I get

```
--with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
```

but I don't know how to fix this. Could it be an incompatibility between Xcode and f2c?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: It looks like you have a file /usr/local/include, which should be a directory instead...

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

`Permission denied` doesn't mean the installation was successful...

It actually means your user can't install in the specific location.

When installing, use `sudo`, so you'll install with admin privileges.

Usually:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Note the `sudo` before `make install`

Comment: Per the f2c instructions, I did